# Building a BLOB from Base64 string in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function which pings my server and tries to download a file from a DB

```
  const handleDownloadFileData = async (id) => {
    const res = await downloadServiceFileData(id)

    console.log(res.data)
  }
```

the output of res.data looks as so:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QCKRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAABJADAAIAAAAUAAAAXJKGAAcAAAASAAAAcKACAAQAAAABAAAC7qADAAQAAAABAAAFNgAAAAAyMDIxOjAyOjE2IDAxOjE0OjA3AEFTQ0lJAAAAU2NyZWVuc2hvdP/tADhQaG90b3Nob3AgMy4wADhCSU0EBAAAAAAAADhCSU0EJQAAAAAAENQdjNmPALIE6YAJmOz4Qn7/4nYwSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQ...
```

I assume this is some kind of decoded Base64??

Can I build the file from this data and display the file in a new tab perhaps? and if so how?
Sorry for the ignorance but I have never done this type of development before.

**downloadServiceFileData**

```
export async function downloadServiceFileData(fileDataId) {

  try {
    return await awsApiRequest({
      method: 'GET',
      path: `/file-data/${fileDataId}`,

    });
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show `downloadServiceFileData`?

Comment: @kellys I made an update. ```downloadServiceFileData``` is essentially a custom hook that uses ```AWS Amplify``` to ping the cloud server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple fetch api

```
const decodedString = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QCKRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAABJADAAIAAAAUAAAAXJKGAAcAAAASAAAAcKACAAQAAAABAAAC7qADAAQAAAABAAAFNgAAAAAyMDIxOjAyOjE2IDAxOjE0OjA3AEFTQ0lJAAAAU2NyZWVuc2hvdP/tADhQaG90b3Nob3AgMy4wADhCSU0EBAAAAAAAADhCSU0EJQAAAAAAENQdjNmPALIE6YAJmOz4Qn7/4nYwSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQ..."

let type = 'application/octet-stream'
let blob = null;

fetch(`data:${type};base64,${decodedString}`).then(res=>blob =res.blob())
//File constructor
var file = new File([blob], "name");
```

Comment: ```res.blob``` is then something I can store in state and render to the client?

Comment: Blob as its abbreviation suggests, is a collection of binary data stored in a single entity. edited the answer. marked it answer if this answers you question